# Why does Sitecore seem to mangle parentheses in the query string?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, query-string, sitecore7, sitecore7.5

I am noticing something strange with Sitecore and parentheses in the query string.  For some reason Sitecore seems to be doing something odd to the query string.  Here are the steps to reproduce this behavior:

1. Install Sitecore 7.5
2. Create a simple sublayout called TestSublayout
3. On the TestSublayout add an ASP Literal tag called litTest
4. In the code behind for the sublayout, in the Page Load event add the following code: `litTest.Text = Request.QueryString.ToString();`
5. Create a simple item in Sitecore called TestItem and use the Sample Item data template
6. In the presentation details for TestItem, put the TestSublayout in the main placeholder.
7. Build the Visual Studio project and publish the site.
8. Open up a browser and go to http://example.com/testitem.aspx?selecteditem=surf(x)%203D%20Laminates

For some reason, Sitecore does something with the parentheses and this is what you see on the screen:

> selecteditem=surf&%2340%3bx&%2341%3b+3D+Laminates

The reason I believe that Sitecore is doing something, is that I tried these exact same steps on a non-Sitecore project and it worked fine.  The parentheses were not garbled or translated in to anything.  They were just in the string as I would expect like this:

> selecteditem=surf(x)%203D%20Laminates

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try putting that URL in Sitecore ignored URLs and re-run the request to see if it's something in the pipeline interfering?

Comment: Well, if I did that I would get a 404 error.  There is no physical ASPX page called testitem.aspx.

Comment: Yes you're right, apologies. Something very strange going on, URL decoding that value results in `selecteditem=surf&#40;x&#41; 3D Laminates` what happens if you remove the brackets from your querystring?

Comment: It's not something to do with XSS protection is it?

Comment: Probably good to put initial question here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220108/why-is-asp-net-modifying-parentheses-in-the-query-string

Comment: Yeah, once I realized that this had something to do with Sitecore I felt like it needed to be a new question completely.

Comment: I can remove the parentheses and it works fine.  But in my particular situation I need to have the parentheses in the querystring.  It just seems odd because it works fine in regular ASP.NET.  And as far as I know parentheses are allowed characters in a URL.

Comment: Yeah little weird. Other thing it may be is Sitecore considering round brackets as special characters although I can't find anything documented relating to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out from Sitecore that this was a known problem that was fixed in version 7.2 but had not been merged in to the 7.5 release.  So they gave me a patch that fixed the problem.